# Diazo not using theme css file

Tags: plone, diazo

How can I make Diazo to use theme's css file?

Whenever I replace something using (for example):

```
<replace css:theme="#footer" css:content="#portal-footer" />
```

It doesn't use the `#footer` style I defined in the theme's css file. Since I didn't enable Plone's css files either, it behaves as if there was no style at all. I found a workaround by renaming the style on my css file to match the one in Plone (i.e: renamed `#footer` to `#portal-footer`) but then what is the purpose of the theme's css file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the rest of your transformed site get the styles from your stylesheet or none of your styles are applied?

Answer (score 4):

The `replace` statement replaces the entire tag found by the theme selector with the tag found by the content selector, attributes too. So if you want to maintain the original class you will have to append/prepend/replace only the children of that tag:

```xml
<replace css:theme-children="#footer" css:content-children="#portal-footer" />
```

More info:

- http://diazo.org/advanced.html

Comment: Ciao Gacomo! Grazie mille per la tua risposta.